# Express, Mongoose with Custom API send more requests than expected

Tags: mongodb, api, rest, express, mongoose

I have a code that fetch total users set in a document of `stats` collection.
As shown here :

```json
{ stats:"stats", users:50, totalActiveUsers:45 }
```

I made a route in express that will save new user in users collection then call email api and then update the value in stats collection by 1 and I want if the users are 100 then stop accepting.

```js
router.get('/newuser',async (req,res)=\>{
var { email } = req.query;
var stats = await Stats.findOne({status:"stats"}).lean();

if(stats.users == 100){
return res.json({msg:"Sorry 100 Users Already Registered"});
}

await fetch(`https://myemailapi.xyz/?email=${email}`);
await Stats.findOneAndUpdate({status:"stats"},{users:stats.users++});
var user = new User({ email : email });
await user.save();

res.json({msg:"Registered Successfully"});
})
```

When many users register on my website, I see 100 users in `stats` collection but when I check my email api dashboard it shows it have sent 110+ emails.

How do I fix this problem ??

I wanted that 100 users register and 100 emails should be sent.

Comment: This could be an issue of things happening in parallel - if multiple requests came in at roughly the same time, you'd fetch stats twice, they'd both be 99, you'd then email all requests and set the `stats` to be 100 (because you don't use `$inc`).

It seems unlikely that you'd have ten requests closely in parallel with only 110 requests though - how is this being accessed?

Comment: @ZackNewsham It is used in my React website as a REST API. Yeah the issue is of because `things are happening in parallle multiple requests came in at roughly the same time`